# Whats a safe way to 'delete' 'new' data/objects?

Tags: c++

For example, if I create a 'new' instance of an class object and then 'delete' that instance, does that clear (as in free up) all memory used by that instance? What if the instance created 'new' instances of other objects? Would they also be affected?

How exactly does the 'delete' work? Are there any safe rules/tips on how to delete? What if I actually wanted to keep certain things and delete everything else in that instance?

EDIT: In regards to 'Smart Pointers' if I need to delete it at a specific moment can I still do that? And if so, then whats the difference between that and 'new'? (unless smart pointers delete when the application closes unexpectedly?)

Comment: In general, avoid using `new` and `delete`. `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr` are almost always better alternatives.

Comment: What do you mean by "clear"? Do you want it to clean up (i.e. zero out) the memory that was used or do you just want to give it back to the OS?

Comment: These questions are common, there are a lot of answers on stackoverflow. But probably, you should read good book, before ask questions here.

Comment: So vectors use the heap by default? I didn't know that.

Comment: @Zyx2000 using smart pointers avoids using delete but does not avoid the use of new. With C++11 having template argument forwarding it may be possible to create straight into a smart-pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `smart_pointers` instead of raw pointers.

> How exactly does the 'delete' work?

Calls destructor of object and then calls `::operator delete` function, that frees memory.

For 2 first your questions:

Since keyword delete calls destructor of object - you should free memory (if you use some resources, that needs to be freed) manually in destructor.
Simple example

```
class A {};

class B
{
public:
    A() : a(new A()) {}
   ~A() { delete a; /* free a's memory */ }
private:
    A* a;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Rule 1. Don't use `new` unless you have a good reason to.

Rule 2. If you do use `new`, then you must have a corresponding call to `delete` somewhere.

As to what `delete` does: It calls the destructor for the object (if there is one), and then frees the memory. If by "clear" you mean "set the memory that was used to zero or some other value", then typically no. But if you mean "make it usable for other things", then yes, that's exactly what `delete` does.

Comment: So in otherwords, if new instance1 creates new instance2 and instance1 gets 'deleted' instance2 will still exist?

Comment: @Tez it depends... there is not enough information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

No, `delete` does not "clear" the memory or the object in any way. It *does* call the objects destructor, where you should release resource allocated by the object.

Comment: @Tez If the object allocated memory with `new` you release it with `delete`. If the object opened files you close them. Any resource you have "allocated" or "opened" or generally dynamically created, you must "deallocate", "close" or generally free.

Comment: @Tez However, by using e.g. smart pointers, or the other standard C++ library classes and objects, you won't have to do it for those things. Other things _outside_ of C++ world generally needs to be released/closed/free'd.

Answer (score 0):

When creating an object using `new`, memory get's allocated for all members and one *constructor* get's called (depending on which you specified). You can use it to create references there, e.g.:

```
public Foo()
{
    m_bar = new Bar();  // Bar* m_bar;
}
```

However this does not affect the size of the object. The pointer (`m_bar`) **allways** needs 4 bytes (on 32 bit architectures) of memory, so the object is somewhat about 8 bytes in size (at least - 4 bytes for `m_bar` and 4 bytes for the pointer to the constructor) <sup>1</sup>.

The exact opposite is the *destructor*, that get's called when using `delete`. You can use it to free all references:

```
public ~Foo()
{
    if (m_bar)  // If the pointer is not NULL, thus pointing anywhere.
        delete m_bar;  // Calls destructor of "Bar" and free it's memory.
}
```

So calling `delete`, calls the destructor and frees the memory the object occupies, but not automatically the memeory referenced objects (like `m_bar` in here) use. You have to take care, that those objects are getting deleted within the destructor. If you forget to call delete for `m_bar`, it will probably end in what we call a *memory leak*.

Using `new` and `delete` is valid for scenarios, where you need as much performance as possible (e.g. real-time scenarios), but usually you should prefer using [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer).

<sup>1</sup><sub><sup>Note that you cannot really give an statement on the actual size of an object. It depends on how the compiler translates it.</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any safe rules/tips on how to delete?

Yes, famous RAII(Resource allocation is initialization) is the solution. It declares that, all of the memory a class allocated should be deallocated in the constructor. C++ guarantees that even if an exception is thrown, destructor is called and destructor is a safe haven for deallocation.

> What if the instance created 'new' instances of other objects?

You should track them too, you may keep them as members of the class and delete them in the destructor or else you may need complicated procedures to track them.

Answer (score 0):

A regular delete actually does 2 things:

1. Call the destructor of the object that the pointer is pointing to.
2. Frees the memory that is the object itself, i.e. sizeof(object)

Between these two steps, the destructor of any class members gets called (as well as any base class destructors).

Note that this step, i.e. the class members getting deleted, only applies to member objects. If the members are pointers, it will not automatically call "delete" on them. Thus your class's destructor needs to take care of that.

Smart pointers achieve that. A `unique_ptr` will always delete that pointer it is holding on its own destruction. A `shared_ptr` will reduce the reference count on the pointer (which is shared among many shared pointers) and will only delete the pointer if the reference count has gone down to 0.

Because of this, it is often preferable to use objects rather than pointers as you do not need to call delete.

Within the scope of a function, this is particularly important, as an exception might be thrown which would throw you out of the function early, before you have reached the clean-up stage. However for an automatic object, exiting its scope even this way will invoke its destructor. (This is why you have to enforce a policy that destructors cannot throw, just in case this scenario is occurring).

Within the scope of a class it is less important, as you can put the logic into your destructor. However you then have to take more care about when happens if your class gets copied or assigned, and what happens if your constructor throws (whereby the destructor will not be called).

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is no such safe way to accomplish this unless with the help of smart pointer trick etc. You are free to use 'new' and 'delete', so you are responsible for the memory management.